# Led blinking at a given frequency - Arduino and Labview

Tags: arduino, labview, led

I'm trying to make a led to blink at a frequency given in a Numeric Control in Labview. I've connected Arduino to Labview using COM4. IThis is the code written in the Arduino IDE:

```c
char command;
String string;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {string = "";}

  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    command = ((byte)Serial.read());
    if(command == ':')
    {
      break;
    }

    else
    {
      string += command;
    }

    delay(1);
  }

  if(string.toInt() > 0 ) 
  {
    TempOn();
    TempOff();
  }

  }
  void TempOn()
  {
     long y= string.toInt();
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
     delay(y);
  }
  void TempOff()
  {
    long y= string.toInt();
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(y);
  }
}
```

If I try to make it blink for a certain value, such as 1000 (I write the following code from below), it works perfectly for that value!

```c
if(string == "1000" ) 
{
  TempOn();
  TempOff();
}
```

I don't understand why it won't work for a general case...

This is the code in Labview (Block Diagram):

[image]

Comment: It looks as if your Arduino code is expecting the time delay string to be terminated with a colon, but your LabVIEW code isn't sending a colon after the digits of the number. Also the LabVIEW code is going to keep transmitting the number every 10 ms, so if (say) the numeric control is set to 1000 then the data stream is going to look like `10001000100010001000` etc. You want to append the terminating character to the string before you pass it to VISA Write, and probably only send the value when you click a button or when the value changes (e.g. using the control's Value Change event).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the serial monitor combined with Serial.print(""); to verify that anything is coming over the serial port?

In LabVIEW you may want to try adding an end of line contast ("\r\n") to your numeric since some serial devices need this to know when a command is finished executing.